# Character encoding - empty rectangles

Tags: 14.04, unicode, character-set

More and more recently I see empty rectangles in text areas on the web. I think it is Ubuntu 14.04's character encoding/Unicode libraries not being up to date but I don't know. I also think it is mostly emoji but cannot actually see the characters to know for sure.

How can I fix this?

The webpages do have a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in them.

[image]

UPDATE: Here is the webpage, https://docs.amazee.io/changelog.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a font problem. None of the fonts installed on your system include the three Unicode characters after "with a" (*). As a fallback, rectangles are drawn instead.

The solution is to install the right font. I can't recommand one since no one font can cover the whole Unicode set (which is huuuuge).

(*) On this webpage, they are [U+1F3C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f199/index.htm), [U+1F199](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4aa/index.htm) and [U+1F4AA][4]

[update following @wjandrea's comment] Ubuntu provides support for those characters with package `ttf-ancient-fonts`. To install it type this command:

```
apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

Comment: Thanks, so maybe in this case it is expecting Helvetica. https://docs.amazee.io/changelog.html

Comment: Tried this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/emoji-one-font-linux-unicode-9-0 and http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-color-emoji-linux-google-chrome-noto but no go yet.

Comment: @ElijahLynn Try this: [How To Enable Emoji On Ubuntu In One Easy Step](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/see-install-use-emoji-symbols-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: A big thanks @wjandrea, that works! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see those 3 characters in Android devices. The "running man", up symbol, and bicep muscle. Follow the link @xhienne refers to by listing chars, then click on "fonts that support". Seems certain you need an emoji font.  Look at the display on one of your mystery characters: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f199/fontsupport.htm

Comment: In ubuntu, open Character Map (a gnome function, command line gucharmap) and hit search, put in U+1F3C3. That takes me to running man. If you see nothing, that explains trouble. I am  sure font package you need to install is "fonts-symbola".   When I right click in CM, it says symbol a.